# Youtube iFrame API cover image -- for Youtube Development team

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api, youtube-iframe-api

This is more for Youtube developers than the populace at wide since the API documentation mentions their developers watch here.

Can you please add an option to the Youtube iframe API to allow the cover image to be displayed with a 'background-size: contain' vs the default 'background-size: cover'.

Anytime I embed a Youtube video to a div that is not properly proportioned to the cover image 1920x1080, the image gets cut off. Currently the only solution available to me for a responsive layout is to use JavaScript & resize events to dynamically change the proportion of the container element. This is a very unnecessary use of JS for something that is literally as simply as a CSS value that could be an option in the API when I create my player. Something like the code block here.

```
    player = new YT.Player(
        'ytPlayer',
        {
            height: '100%',
            width: '100%',
            'background-color': '#000',
            videoId: [video id],
            playerVars: {
                autohide: 1,
                autoplay: 0,
                coverimagesize: '[contain/cover]'
            }
        }
    );
```

Comment: I can also suggest to file a [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/entry?template=YouTube%20(Enhancement%20Request)) so that the Engineers can attend your issue.

Comment: I submitted it. Thanks!